# Using back substitution to solve the matrix system with fractions

Tags: linear-algebra

I was asked to use back substitution to solve the system:
$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccc|c|c}
   1 & 3/2 &1/2&a&9/4\\
   0 & 1&1&b&-1/2\\
0&0&1&c&0
\end{array}
\right] $$

The answer =

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{c}
   3\\
   -1/2\\
0
\end{array} 
\right] $$

I understand how to perform the back substitution and get the first two answers: $c = 0$ and $b = -\frac{1}{2}$

But how do we get $a = 3$?

The fractional back substitution must be getting me confused.

Comment: $a - \frac{3}{4} + 0 = \frac{9}{4} \implies a=3.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you haven’t figured it out yet, your system of equations is

$a+3/2b+1/2c=9/4\\
b+c=-1/2\\
c=0$

Now you simply work your way up, “back substituting” what you get from each rung of the ladder. Third line already gives you $c=0$ in plain sight. So now you have

$b+c=-1/2\\
b+0=-1/2\\
b=-1/2$

Now the first line tells you
$a+3/2b+1/2c=9/4\\
a+3/2(-1/2)+0=9/4\\
a-3/4=9/4\\
a=12/4=3$

So your answers are $a=3, b=-1/2, c=0$. A system of equations in rref or row echelon form are especially conducive to being solved via back substitution, because what else would you do? Add equation 1 to equation 3? Then you lose the information that c already equals 0.

Note you don’t have to back substitute one line at a time. You could substitute what you get from the bottommost equation into all the equations above it at once.